# How to debug nodejs app that is importing a library twice?

Tags: node.js

I'm using a library called `yjs` that needs to be imported just once, across all dependencies. Currently, when I run my app, I get the following warning message from `yjs`:

```
Yjs was already imported. Importing different versions of Yjs often leads to issues.
```

How can I see what is importing this library, and where the double-import might be coming from?

When I run `pnpm why yjs` it tells me a little info:

```
$ pnpm why yjs
Legend: production dependency, optional only, dev only

relm-server@1.0.0 /home/duane/Relm/relm/server

dependencies:
y-websocket 1.3.18-canadaduane
├─┬ y-leveldb 0.1.1
│ └── yjs 13.5.27 peer
└── yjs 13.5.27 peer
yjs 13.5.27
```

But it isn't showing me some of the places that I *know* are also importing yjs. For example, this project has several pnpm workspaces, and other workspaces that use yjs are dependencies of this one--but they aren't visible in the `pnpm why` report.

Is there a way to "print" a log of import statements as the app runs, and show what js files are importing what packages/files?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75649674/node-esm-trace-where-file-was-imported-from

Answer (score 3):

In nodejs 18 (and I think nodejs 16), there is an import loader hook mechanism that can be used if set up on the command line (Note: this mechanism is not available to "any old package", as that would be a security concern):

1. Create a file named `es-import-trace.js` in your project root (wherever you normally run `node`):

```
export const load = async (url, context, defaultLoad) => {
    console.log('import: ' + url);
    return await defaultLoad(url, context);
};
```

2. Use node's `--loader` command-line argument to run your node app with the es-import-trace.js file:

```
node --loader ./es-import-trace.js dist/server.js
```

3. You will get output such as the following, allowing you to see each import:

```
import: file:///home/duane/Relm/relm/server/dist/server.js
import: node:fs
import: file:///home/duane/Relm/relm/server/dist/config.js
import: file:///home/duane/Relm/relm/server/dist/server_ws.js
import: file:///home/duane/Relm/relm/server/dist/db/db.js
... etc. ...
```

Comment: I can't believe I was the first up-vote for this - it's *so* helpful!