# Node ESM trace where file was imported from

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

Consider:

```
// foo.mjs
import './bar.mjs';
```

```
// bar.mjs
throw new Error('bar failed');
```

Running `node foo.mjs` gives:

```
file:///.../bar.mjs:1
throw new Error('bar failed');
      ^

Error: bar failed
    at file:///.../bar.mjs:1:7
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:198:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:385:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:61:12)
```

Note that the stack trace does not mention `foo` anywhere. This is not helpful, especially if the error is specifically about how and when `bar` is imported. For example, it might be a singleton and you're mistakenly creating a duplicate by loading it from both `import` and `require`, or it might need something else to be set up on the global first and you're loading it in the wrong order.

Given an error like this, how do you get a trace of where the module was imported from?

I am currently using node 16. Node 18 produces a shorter but similarly lacking stack:

```
Error: bar failed
    at file:///.../bar.mjs:1:7
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

Comment: With `import()` and top-level await, multiple modules might be importing/loading the same module at the same time, so I guess this is impossible in general. But since this is a nodejs-specific question, I would recommend to open an issue in the project, they might be able to produce more helpful error messages.

Comment: Opened https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/46992

Answer (score 4):

You can trace the module loader by running your process with `NODE_DEBUG=esm` — lots of output, but helpful.

Comment: It shows what modules are loaded but it doesn't show from whom a module is imported, so it doesn't seem helpful for getting an import trace.